# How to let different text lines take equal space?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<p>gypsum -> triton</p>
<p>antimony -> juno.lunarirc.net</p>
<p>bismuth -> apollo.lunarirc.net</p>

gypsum -> triton    
antimony -> juno    
bismuth -> apollo
```

How can I make the `->` align like:

```
gypsum   -> triton    
antimony -> juno    
bismuth  -> apollo
```

Comment: maybe if you had some HTML and CSS you tried we could help you from there ...

Comment: I don't have much code beside the paragraphs, but so far I tried many things even made 3 column layout for just that. But I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: You can use table structure to do that. It can help and can be easy to do

Comment: I would use a list and the table-layout to display it http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NROrrV ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use tables.

```html
 <table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <td>gypsum</td>
    <td>triton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>antimony</td>
    <td>juno</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: or a list displayed as a table ;) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NROrrV

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>gypsum</td>
    <td> -> </td>
    <td>triton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>antimony</td>
    <td> -> </td>
    <td>juno</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bismuth </td>
    <td> -> </td>
    <td>apollo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```